# Selinux deny root user

Tags: selinux

I am using SELinux in my centos server. I am trying to change context of the file located in the `/var/www/html` as a root user.

Root user is also not able to make any changes in the context of the file. Let me know how could a root user change the context the file in Selinux.

The context of the root user is as follows

```
unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

Answer (score 2):

Use chcon to switch the SELinux context, ex:

```
chcon system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put the file in question in the default context for its current location? (i.e. put it in the context that would be typical for a file in `/var/lib/www`)

If so you can use `restorecon`

```
restorecon -v /var/lib/www/my_file.txt
```

You can use `-n` to see what `restorecon` will change without actually changing anything

```
restorecon -v -n /var/lib/www/my_file.txt
```